# How to delete a string in my files?

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, regular-expression, string

So I want to match all below then remove those lines of string.

```
[MTT-5634](https://my.atlassian.net/browse/MTT-5634)
[MCC-123](https://my.atlassian.net/browse/MCC-123)
[MTT-7965]: https://my.atlassian.net/browse/MTT-7965
https://my.atlassian.net/browse/MTT-7965
```

I have tried

```
sed -e 's/\[(MTT|MCC)-[0-9]{3,4}\?]\?://g;s!.\?http[s]\?://\S*!!g' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us more examples, including both lines that should be kept and lines that should be deleted. You seem to also want to find `MCC-` and apparently can have a variable list of numbers, but what else? And do you want to delete the line or keep it as an empty line?

Comment: I have updated it, to make more sense @terdon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't enable the `-E`xtended regex, so you will need to escape a few special character such as `(`, `)`, `|`, `{`, `}`, `?`. You also have a trailing `:` in your first sed statement that should be removed. Also, you forgot to escape the closing bracket `]`.

Your own corrected (but not improved) command should be:

```
sed -e 's/\[\(MTT\|MCC\)-[0-9]\{3,4\}\?\]\?//g;s!.\?http[s]\?://\S*!!g' infile
```

See [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](/q/32907/72456)

Comment: hello so -e and -E not same? Sorry I got confused

Comment: @Beelzebub Hello. Of course they are not. see `man sed` for description of each.